# How to create linux tui like this one on the picture

Tags: linux, terminal, tui

Could someone share how can i create tui like this one with input boxex and search ?
What do i need?
[image: tui]

Comment: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/ BTW: Your question is off topic as it explicitly asks to search for a library. Not my rule :-)

Comment: I did not know that i need alibrary for that :/
Thanx for your answer btw

Answer (score 1):

Normally programmers use a ready to use library like [ncurses](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).

You can also do it by hand if you really have to much time. To get for example the border lines of a dialog window you have to take a look at the current code page your terminal is emulating, for example: [Code Page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850). As you can see, you will find single and double line boarders and also crossings and so on. Now you have to move your cursor to a given position, print that char from the code page and ... lots of work. Moving cursors itself can also be done by simple chars from your emulated terminal by using [escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

As said: Instead of doing it all by hand, simply use a lib like ncurses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some python libraries like [pyTermTk](https://github.com/ceccopierangiolieugenio/pyTermTk) or [textual](https://github.com/Textualize/textual), there is wide selection of
[libraries](https://github.com/rothgar/awesome-tuis) to choose from.